Advice for what API style in Vue I should use to build an app about learning spoken languages
I am a senior at a NYC high school and I'm participating in the Congressional App Challenge. I want to build an app that will teach users the basics of writing and speaking prominent African languages.
I have limited experience in building apps as I have only created basic functioning applications on Xcode. I want this app to have a functional UI while being visually pleasing for the judges. I do have experience in coding in general. Normally I code in C++ and Python, so I am leaning towards using the Options API because it's a similar style to the OOP languages I know. However because I think this might be a complex app to build, maybe I should use Composition API?
In terms of how the app will be structured, I want each language in the app to have a separation into Basic, Intermediate and Advanced in terms of the coursework. This would be modeled similar to Duolingo where the user has to type in the answers to the question. I would also like to include minigames similar to those of Quizlet Match or one where word falls from sky and the user needs to catch the right one or the game ends. These would help make learning the languages fun for the user. However I'm not sure if I can do this using Vue.
Can someone please advise me as to what I should do?
